# Is there a limit on the number of sessions for Azure Web SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are using the Azure SQL Database (Web Edition) for a MVC3 ASP.NET/EF5 application.

Is there a limit to the number of sessions that this SQL Database setup supports? I am just wondering whether any delays that we are getting is due to some form of queuing or pooling. Currently we have about 5 concurrent users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Azure Web edition database should support a high number of concurrent users - we've had applications running that issue thousands of queries per minute against Web databases.

#### Throttling

SQL Azure does implement [database throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn338079.aspx) to maintain performance for all users of the platform. If throttling has been applied to the current operation you'll receive error 40501. [The link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn338079.aspx) I've provided also shows you how to determine why throttling is being applied. If you receive this error you can treat it as a transient error and wait before retrying.

It doesn't sound like your connections are being throttled, because you mention only 5 concurrent users and talk about delays, whereas the throttling error would occur pretty quickly.

#### Transient error handling

If you're getting connection timeouts etc you need to handle them as [transient errors](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling). Transient errors are timeouts or dropped connections, as well as error codes 10054, 10053, 40501 (throttling as described above) and 40197 (usually because an upgrade or failover operation is in progress).

You should ensure you implement retry logic to handle transient errors.

#### Query performance

If you're executing long running queries you can check which ones are slow by logging into the database management URL:

`https://<database-id>.database.windows.net/#$database=<database-name>`

Log in and click "Query Performance" - take a look at the longest running queries at the top.

Comment: But what about the number of *sessions*?

Comment: @greg84, Thank you for the comprehensive reply. I use NewRelic, with the SQL Plugin, and with this I spotted that query durations were surprisingly variable, ie 200- 900ms for the same query, which leads me to think that there would be caused by something in Azure SQL Database. Also in the back of my mind is whether I will get a better experience using MS's new Database services, ie Standard S1.

Comment: Yes, would be interested to hear if there is a max session number for the web edition. In Standard S1, it is 200, so will this be more or less that Web Edition?

Comment: Just looked at the Azure Management Portal. Timings look fine, 0,1ms or 2ms/Sec. Run Counts for the most popular query is 67K. So all looks fine, which is all a bit weird as NewRelic reports one query taking 4s to complete, and on another occasion, 1 sec. Same query, different time. The query is the membership service's procedure called: dbo.aspnet_membership_getuserbyname - EXECUTEPROCEDURE

Comment: @usr I've always thought of connections and sessions in SQL Server to mean a similar thing, unless you've enabled MARS - where multiple sessions may share a single connection. I've just had to do a Google to check I wasn't talking total junk, and found this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13698/what-is-the-difference-between-a-connection-and-a-session

Comment: @SamJolly The query time variance you're seeing is probably as expected in a shared hosting environment - where the databases of other users are on the same server as yours. You'll definitely see an improvement with the new SQL Azure services, but you'll pay a premium for the better performance. Alternatively you could provision a VM and install SQL Server on it to guarantee a dedicated resource. The only problem with this is that you'd need to handle patching, backup and failover/clustering by yourself. It's a tradeoff between performance, cost and labour.

Comment: Interesting link, but what about the number of connections then?